# How to know when a process has exited?

Tags: java, process, exit

For a Java Process, I see a method to get the exit code, but how do I know when the process exited?

I'd like to fire an event when my Process is finished running...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Process.waitFor()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor())

If you want to fire an event without stopping your current thread, start a thread that launches the process, calls waitFor(), and then fires the event when the time is right.

```
Thread.start(new Runnable() {
  public void main() {
    Process p = startProcess()
    p.waitFor()
    fireEvent()
  }
})
```